# How to Specify Python Version PyInstaller Uses?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have Python 2.7 & 3.5 on my system.  I'm using OS X 10.12.  Python 2.7 is the default on the system.

When building PyInstaller using...

```
pyinstaller myscript.py
```

...PyInstaller uses Python 2.7.

Perhaps I missed it, but I can't find anywhere in PyInstaller documentation that would allow me to specify the Python version.

Does anyone know how constrain PyInstaller to use the non-default Python version 3.5?

I've tried building using Macports.

After using command....

```
sudo port select python python35
```

I get a confirmed...

```
Selecting 'python35' for 'python' succeeded. 'python35' is now active.
```

Then when trying to build using...

```
pyinstaller main.py --onefile
```

PyInstaller shows it's building with 2.7...

```
68 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2.1
68 INFO: Python: 2.7.13
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing pyinstaller use `pip3 install pyinstaller`

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem on Windows(10) using venv:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

I first installed the version of python (3.5.2), that I thought would work with PyInstaller (3.2.1). Then I created a virtual environment. Next I activated that venv. Installed pyinstaller and ran pyinstaller.

It made my executable ok, whereas PyInstaller: 3.2.1 failed miserably with Python: 3.6.1.

Here is some pseudo cmd line commands, but you get the idea from reading the URL above.

```
Python35-32\python -m venv <venvpath>
cd <venvpath>
.\Scripts\activate
pip install PyInstaller
pyinstaller -F -c buildtest.py
```