# How to tell Pyinstaller to use Python 3.5 instead of 2.7?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to build an executable out of my .py script using Pyinstaller. The problem is that it builds it using Python 2.7 instead of Python 3.5, so my executable won't even run.

```
cali@californiki-pc ~/Desktop $ pyinstaller --onefile Vocabulary.py 
25 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2.1
25 INFO: Python: 2.7.12
26 INFO: Platform: Linux-4.4.0-72-generic-x86_64-with-LinuxMint-18.1-serena
26 INFO: wrote /home/cali/Desktop/Vocabulary.spec
31 INFO: UPX is not available.
32 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/home/cali/Desktop', '/home/cali/Desktop']
32 INFO: checking Analysis
33 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
33 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
34 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
139 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
160 INFO: Caching module hooks...
164 INFO: Analyzing /home/cali/Desktop/Vocabulary.py
246 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   _xmlplus
1991 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
2209 INFO: Loading module hooks...
2209 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
2210 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
2959 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-httplib.py"...
2960 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
3427 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
3428 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
3435 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
3663 INFO: Looking for eggs
3663 INFO: Python library not in binary depedencies. Doing additional searching...
3707 INFO: Using Python library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0
3710 INFO: Warnings written to /home/cali/Desktop/build/Vocabulary/warnVocabulary.txt
3768 INFO: checking PYZ
3768 INFO: Building PYZ because out00-PYZ.toc is non existent
3768 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /home/cali/Desktop/build/Vocabulary/out00-PYZ.pyz
4122 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /home/cali/Desktop/build/Vocabulary/out00-PYZ.pyz completed successfully.
4172 INFO: checking PKG
4172 INFO: Building PKG because out00-PKG.toc is non existent
4172 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
7322 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg completed successfully.
7336 INFO: Bootloader /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-64bit/run
7336 INFO: checking EXE
7336 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
7336 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
7337 INFO: Appending archive to ELF section in EXE /home/cali/Desktop/dist/Vocabulary
7352 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc completed successfully.
```

How can I overcome the issue?

@EDIT:

I tried to install Pyinstaller using `pip3 install pyinstaller` as Claudio suggested, but I am getting:

```
cali@californiki-pc ~/Desktop $ pip3 install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached PyInstaller-3.2.1.tar.bz2
Collecting setuptools (from pyinstaller)
  Using cached setuptools-35.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting appdirs>=1.4.0 (from setuptools->pyinstaller)
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting packaging>=16.8 (from setuptools->pyinstaller)
  Using cached packaging-16.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.6.0 (from setuptools->pyinstaller)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyparsing (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools->pyinstaller)
  Using cached pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: pyinstaller
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyinstaller ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-42qpk7iy/pyinstaller/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpmmn5007ppip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyinstaller
  Running setup.py clean for pyinstaller
Failed to build pyinstaller
Installing collected packages: appdirs, six, pyparsing, packaging, setuptools, pyinstaller
  Running setup.py install for pyinstaller ... done
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.3 packaging-16.8 pyinstaller-3.2.1 pyparsing-2.2.0 setuptools-35.0.1 six-1.10.0
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Specify Python Version PyInstaller Uses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525896/how-to-specify-python-version-pyinstaller-uses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To overcome the problem you face install PyInstaller using:

> pip3 install pyinstaller

Then take care that you run the right one (there will then be two of them in different locations, one in the path of Python2.7 modules and one in the path of Python3.5 modules)

Just installed PyInstaller for Python 3.5 on my machine:

```
$ pip3 install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
Collecting setuptools (from pyinstaller)
  Using cached setuptools-35.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.6.0 (from setuptools->pyinstaller)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting appdirs>=1.4.0 (from setuptools->pyinstaller)
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting packaging>=16.8 (from setuptools->pyinstaller)
  Using cached packaging-16.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyparsing (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools->pyinstaller)
  Using cached pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, appdirs, pyparsing, packaging, setuptools, pyinstaller
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.3 packaging-16.8 pyinstaller-3.2.1 pyparsing-2.0.3 setuptools-20.7.0 six-1.10.0
```

It installs without problems ... Hmmm ...

Try:

```
sudo -H pip3 install setuptools --upgrade
```

(see for more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819221/why-is-python-setup-py-saying-invalid-command-bdist-wheel-on-travis-ci) - you are not alone with this problem)

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
py -3.5 -m PyInstaller Vocabulary.py --onefile
```

I think it is case sensitive

Comment: what does this command do? why it should help to solve the OP problem?

Comment: OP asks how to use python 3.5 instead of 2.7. py -3.5 -m will force python 3.5.

Answer (score -2):

Just set an option -upx-dir in pyinstaller specifying your path for python 3.5. It can be the virtual environment too. For instance:

```
pyinstaller --upx-dir="$HOME/virtual-envs/<your-virtual-env>/lib/python3.5/site-packages/" <your-script>.py'
```